# The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: azure, push-notification, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending the push notification to Android and apple devices from ASP.NET Core Web API. But most of the time in between push failed and I am getting an error

> The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid

I do not understand this.

I am using the NotificationHub nuget package in my project. Package version in 4.0.0.

I am showing my code here - please help me with this issue.

```
public async static Task SendPushNotificationToDevice(HubNotification hub notification) 
{
    if (hubNotification != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString
  (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubConnectionString"],
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubName"], true);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubNotification.DeviceId) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubNotification.DeviceType))
            {
                // check if the already registered device
                var registationDescriptions = hub.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync(hubNotification.ToUserEmail, 100)
               .Result;

               foreach (var registrationDescription in registationDescriptions) 
               {
                   // We shouldn't have any extra registrations; delete if we do.
                   hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registrationDescription);
               }

               // set message
               hubNotification.Message = string.Format(hubNotification.Message);

               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubNotification.Message)) 
               {
                   string jsonPayLoad = string.Empty;

                   NotificationOutcome outcome;

                   if (hubNotification.DeviceType.ToLower().Contains("android")) 
                   {
                       var registeredNewDevice = hub.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(
                      hubNotification.DeviceId.Replace("-", ""),
                      new[]{hubNotification.ToUserEmail})
                           .Result;

                      jsonPayLoad = "{ " data ": " +
                                    "{ " message
                                    ": "
                                    " + hubNotification.Message.Trim() + "
                                    "," +
                                    "" ListId
                                    ": "
                                    " + hubNotification.ListId + "
                                    "," +
                                    "" notificationType
                                    ": "
                                    " + hubNotification.NotificationType + "
                                    "," +
                                    "" IsOwner
                                    ": "
                                    " + hubNotification.IsOwner + "
                                    "," +
                                    "" ListName
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.ListName + "
               "," +
               "" ListType
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.ListType + "
               "," +
               "" badge
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.badge + "
               "," +
               "" inProgress
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.InProgress + "
               "," +
               "" headercolor
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.ListHeaderColor + "
               "," +
               "" titlecolor
               ": "
               " + hubNotification.ListHeaderTitleColor + "
               "," +
               "" sound
               ":"
               " + hubNotification.Sound + "
               "," +
               "" userProfileId
               ":"
               " + hubNotification.ToUserProfileId.ToString().Trim() + "
               "," +
               "" type ":" sendfriend "}}";

           outcome = hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(
                            jsonPayLoad, hubNotification.ToUserEmail)
                         .Result;
         } else {
           hubNotification.Sound = hubNotification.Sound + ".caf";
           var registeredNewDevice =
               hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(
                      hubNotification.DeviceId.Replace("-", ""),
                      new[]{hubNotification.ToUserEmail})
                   .Result;

         new[] { hubNotification.ToUserEmail }).Result;
          jsonPayLoad = "{ " aps ": " +
          "{ " alert
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.Message.Trim() + "
          "," +
          "" ListId
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.ListId + "
          "," +
          "" notificationType
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.NotificationType + "
          "," +
          "" IsOwner
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.IsOwner + "
          "," +
          "" ListName
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.ListName + "
          "," +
          "" ListType
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.ListType + "
          "," +
          "" badge
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.badge + "
          "," +
          "" InProgress
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.InProgress + "
          "," +
          "" headercolor
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.ListHeaderColor + "
          "," +
          "" titlecolor
          ": "
          " + hubNotification.ListHeaderTitleColor + "
          "," +
          "" sound
          ":"
          " + hubNotification.Sound + "
          "," +
          "" userProfileId
          ":"
          " + hubNotification.ToUserProfileId.ToString().Trim() + "
          "," +
          "" type ":" sendfriend "}}";
         outcome = hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(jsonPayLoad,
                                           hubNotification.ToUserEmail)
          .Result;
         }

         // check the response
         if (outcome != null) 
         {
             if (!((outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) ||
                   (outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Unknown))) 
             {
                 // Message send successfully!!
                         }
                    }
                }
                //});
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
             // LogError(ex.Message, "SendPushNotificationToDevice");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To address the "Push Notification System handle invalid" error in your ASP.NET Core Web API, refactor the code by using `await` instead of `.Result` for async calls, ensuring correct and current device tokens, and formatting JSON payloads properly using a library like `Newtonsoft.Json`. Avoid deleting registrations before sending notifications, and improve error handling for detailed insights. Verify the Azure Notification Hub connection settings and ensure they match your app's environment. Update your NuGet packages to the latest versions for bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I already tried all these points. But still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below updated code:

```
public async Task SendPushNotificationToDevice(HubNotification hubNotification) 
{
    if (hubNotification == null) 
    {
        return;
    }

    try 
    {
        var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubConnectionString"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubName"],
            true);

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubNotification.DeviceId) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubNotification.DeviceType))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Serialize the push notification data
        var payload = new
        {
            data = new
            {
                message = hubNotification.Message.Trim(),
                // Other data fields...
            }
            // For iOS 'aps' field...
        };
        string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        NotificationOutcome outcome = null;

        if (hubNotification.DeviceType.ToLower().Contains("android")) 
        {
            outcome = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(jsonPayload, hubNotification.ToUserEmail);
        } 
        else 
        {
            outcome = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(jsonPayload, hubNotification.ToUserEmail);
        }

        if (outcome != null && outcome.State != NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) 
        {
            // Push notification sent successfully
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // LogError(ex.ToString(), "SendPushNotificationToDevice");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working I am still getting the same result.